# How to type Redux-Toolkit createListenerMiddleware listener entry

Tags: typescript, redux, middleware, redux-toolkit

I've been integrating redux-toolkits [createListenerMiddleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware) recently but I'm kinda stuck at the moment. I'm trying to type some of my "**listener entries**" but can't seem to manage it. Intelli-sense just doesn't make sense to me and I can't find any examples in the docs or online for that matter. The goal is to have the `listenerApi` argument typed so I can use the `getState()` function without having to do any typecasting.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  actionCreator: toggleSomething, // Action generator from reducer createSlice
  effect: async (
    action: AnyAction,
    listenerApi: ListenerEffectAPI<AppState, Dispatch> // Trying to type this in some way :[
  ): Promise<void> => {
    const state = (await listenerApi.getState()) as AppState; // TODO: type this better
  },
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`startListening` is designed to infer the correct TS types as much as possible.

Assuming that your action creator ( `toggleSomething` ) is typed correctly (which it should be if you're following [our RTK TS usage guidelines](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript)), `startListening` will correctly infer the type of `action` inside of the `effect` callback.

That leaves the type of `getState`.  RTK and TS can't know that ahead of time, because the middleware gets added to the store.  That's why we we designed the API to let you create a "pre-typed" version of `startListening` that has the correct state type applied, as shown in the API docs here:

- https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware#typescript-usage

Example:

```
// listenerMiddleware.ts
import { createListenerMiddleware, addListener } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import type { TypedStartListening, TypedAddListener } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

import type { RootState, AppDispatch } from './store'

export const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware()

export type AppStartListening = TypedStartListening<RootState, AppDispatch>

export const startAppListening =
  listenerMiddleware.startListening as AppStartListening

export const addAppListener = addListener as TypedAddListener<
  RootState,
  AppDispatch
>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. I didn't have my `startListening` typed as per the docs mentioned :)